# module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'model' Unresolved reference 'module'

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am creating A Realtime chat app using python,django,pycharm.
there is following error occurs
"Unresolved reference 'models'"

Comment: please post full track back

Comment: You have given us very little information to go on. At a minimum we would need to see the traceback and a small, relevant section of code from where the problem is occurring. If possible you should provide a *minimal* example that can be executed by other people and demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the case that you have the wrong interpreter used by Pycharm.
You can configure this here:
`Settings -> Project: -> Project Interpreter`

Check your installed packages, they should contain the installed Django package, if not, install it there via GUI or via terminal.

This should fix your issue.